# Lambert W function identity from differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, lambert-w

For constants $v,K$ and a function $C(t)$, can you prove that if :

$$ \frac{dc}{dt} = - \frac{vc(t)}{K + c(t)},~\text{with } c(0) = c_0 $$

Then the solution:

$$ \left[ K \ln  c(t) + c(t) \right]_{c_0}^{c(t)} = [-vt]_0^t  $$

Implies the closed form:

$$c(t) = K \cdot W\left(\frac{c_0}{K}exp(\frac{-vt + c_0}{K})\right) $$

Where $W$ is the *Lambert W function*.

I can prove $$ce^c = c_0 exp(\frac{-vt + c_0}{K}) $$ so i'm close, but clearly missing some $K $ terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sub $c = Ky$ then you will get
$$
Ky' = -v\frac{Ky}{K+Ky} = -v\frac{y}{1+y}
$$
Thus
$$
\ln y + y = -\frac{v}{K}t + \lambda
$$

or
$$
y\mathrm{e}^y = A\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v}{K}t}
$$

Now 
$y= W(x)$ corresponds to
$$
y\mathrm{e}^y = x
$$
Thus letting 
$$
x = A\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v}{K}t}
$$

We find that
$$
y = W\left(A\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v}{K}t}\right)
$$
Then finally
$$
c = K W\left(A\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v}{K}t}\right)
$$
Use conditions now. So the only bit that would have helped you was the definition of the lambert function.